# How facebook reloads the entire page without reloading the chat-related stuff?

Tags: javascript

When you browse facebook and click a link on it for example (a friend profile, the home button etc) all the page get refreshed but not the chat.

How can you tell the browser to reload the page but don't reload a part of it?

Comment: The magic word may be AJAX. (I hate buzzwords...) I don't use Facebook, but they are either loading the "whole page" using an ajax request and updating the DOM with the loaded data, or they are loading the whole page and updating the chat to look the same as it did before.

Comment: So do you mean every link on facebook is AJAX loaded... It could be a solution.

Comment: You can easily find out by running Firebug, and choosing the Net panel, and then loading the page - you should see what types of requests they're doing.

Comment: @sinelaw: After reading felix answer I think fb can't do that with pure AJAX, because when you click something the url in the address bar changes too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check out [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries). Basically, HTML5 introduced a feature (`history.pushState()`, `history.replaceState()` and `window.onpopstate`) that allows you to change the URL displayed in the address bar without actually reloading the page.

Comment: Nice, but I'd be surprised if that's the (only) method that they're using. Facebook works also if you don't have an HTML5-enabled browser, I'm guessing.

Comment: Yes, it probably works, but it probably downgrades gracefully by storing the chat state (such as open chats) in a cookie, or something. Also, very fast servers.

Comment: Right, it can't be only an AJAX loading because even the address changes too! so it must be something like this felix. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here's what facebook actually seems to do:

1. On browsers that support it, they use `history.pushState` (i've tested up-to-date chrome and firefox)
2. On IE (which doesn't support pushState), and I'm guessing on other browsers too, they don't change the url at all - they use hash tags. There's a javascript handler on the click event which replaces the href from `facebook.com/events` to `facebook.com/?sfrm=1#!/events/` (or similar)

Answer (score -1):

Could be with AJAX behaviors or with something like :

```
<body>
  <iframe src="content.php" id="content_frame">
    <p>Browser does not support iframes.</p>
  </iframe>
  <iframe src="chat.php" id="chat_frame">
    <p>Browser does not support iframes.</p>
  </iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't give a -1 here but facebook does everything but not this

Comment: The final part of the question was "How can you tell the browser to reload the page but don't reload a part of it?". So I specified a way to do that which didn't mean Facebook does do that.